# Animating an image along a polyline on a loop in google maps

Tags: google-maps, animation, polyline

I'm playing around with some mapping code and trying to create a basic movement loop using google maps.

At this stage all i'm trying to do is have a predefined image move along a poly-line of defined points.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() 
    {
    var mapProp =   {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(55.9449229,-3.1966657),
                zoom:10,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var target = {
    url: 'image.gif', // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
};
//create a bouncing image
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  map:map,
  position: {lat: 55.9449229, lng: -3.1966657},

  icon:target,
animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
  });
//try and have a image walk round
 var lineSymbol = {
         path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,     
          //how big is the icon
          scale: 8,
      //color of the icon
      strokeColor: '#FFFF00'
    };

// Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [{lat: 55.9449229, lng: -3.1966657}, {lat: 55.9149229, lng: -3.1966657},{lat: 55.9149229, lng: -3.1466657}],
      icons: [{icon: lineSymbol, offset: '100%'}],
      map: map
    });         
    animateCircle(line);
marker.setMap(map);
}   
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:800px;height:600px;"></div>
<script>
function animateCircle(line) {
          var count = 0;
          window.setInterval(function() {
        count = (count + 0.05) % 200;

        var icons = line.get('icons');
        icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
        line.set('icons', icons);
    }, 20);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've written this in Notepad++ and saved it as a html file. so you can throw any image you like into it by naming it image with the correct extension.

if you run it, you can see the green circle follows correctly, but when you alter the target on the polyline from 'lineSymbol' to 'target' (which links to the image) it does nothing.

Anyone have any experience with this, it should have been a simple switch i would have thought but i'm obviously missing something in the syntax to use an image in this way. Thanks for any insight into this! finding valid documentation on google maps is challenging!

Edit: --- Following the comments and the realization that i'm trying to use a square plug in a round hole, I've got another idea that I might be able to use to replace it and would like on opinion on if its plausible.

The image is to follow a simple closed loop shape like a circle, square..etc, looping round continually.

Would integrating between 2 sets of GPS points to create a smooth movement work, altering the integration interval appropriately to define the speed.

In effect having an array of coordinates outlining a path, then having a function take element[0] and gradually alter its values towards that of element[1], and upon them either being the same or about to pass, repeat again using element[1] and element[2]?

I've yet to see any examples of this online so I may be going on a tangent again, any advice along this line? the more adaptable the method the better. would be nice not to have to rely on a google map function. thanks

Comment: `Polyline` accepts `IconSequence` - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#IconSequence as icon param, which is a `Symbol` - https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols. And `Symbol` is SVG: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/. So you will have to use SVG instead of GIF. If your GIF is complex and can not be easily presented with SVG path: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData, you have a problem :)

Comment: [Example animating a marker along a polyline (from the directions service)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html)

Comment: is there a hidden resource in the "directions service" example stated above? I went to page source and coppied the content into a html file to test it and poke at it to learn, but it just states New Text Document.html:226 Uncaught TypeError: polyline.Distance is not a function